# Symfony 5: The server couldn't send a response: Ensure that the backend is working properly

Tags: rest, symfony, post, symfony5

I am trying to send a modification through Json to my project in Symfony 5, but I only get error responses, as if there is no Url, I have not inserted any API key or any header, I have searched for a guide but I cannot find it:

UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class UserController
{
    private $userRepository;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/user/", name="add_user", methods={"POST"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function add(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        $firstName = $data['firstName'];
        $lastName = $data['lastName'];
        $email = $data['email'];
        $phoneNumber = $data['phoneNumber'];

        if (empty($firstName) || empty($lastName) || empty($email) || empty($phoneNumber)) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Expecting mandatory parameters!');
        }

        $this->userRepository->saveUser($firstName, $lastName, $email, $phoneNumber);

        return new JsonResponse(['status' => 'User created!'], Response::HTTP_CREATED);
    }
```

UserRepository.php:

```
    public function saveUser($firstName, $lastName, $email, $phoneNumber)
    {
        $newUser = new User();

        $newUser
            ->setFirstName($firstName)
            ->setLastName($lastName)
            ->setEmail($email)
            ->setPhoneNumber($phoneNumber);

        $this->manager->persist($newUser);
        $this->manager->flush();
    }
```

[image]

As for the GET, I have done it correctly and I get an answer with the data.

Comment: What happens if you use your browser to open that URL? Just try a usual `GET` request to check for any response

Answer (score 1):

Your path looks wrong. On the controller action you define the route as:

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/user/", name="add_user", methods={"POST"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
```

The `add_user` is just the internal route name. The url in postman should probably be:

```
https://127.0.0.1:8000/user/
```

Additionally, since you did not get any response, so not even a 404 not found, I assume you do not have a web server running right now. If you use the Symfony CLI-tool you can call the command: `symfony serve` in your project directory to get the web server running. Closing the terminal window or restarting your computer will stop the web server.